# Table width changes unexpectedly while applying colspan to one of its cells

Tags: html, html-table

I want to figure out this as why the size of my table changes unexpectedly when colspan is applied to one of the cells as indicated by the content of the textbox below:

[image: Example screenshot]

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid navy;
}

table {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-family: arial;
  color: #fff5cc;
  margin-top: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="" onsubmit="return ValidateForm()">
  <table border="1" id="tbl">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">Registration No:</td>
      <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="mid" id="mid" class="txtBx" value="" readonly/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Payable Month(s):</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="" class="txtBx" /></td>
      <td>Days(s):</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="" class="txtBx" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">Arrears(Rs):</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="arrear" class="txtBx" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="submit" name="sbmit" id="sbmit" value="Confirm" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

But, when I apply colspan, it becomes like:

[image: Example screenshot 2]

Change made to the code:

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="2">Arrears(Rs):</td>
  <td colspan="2"><input type="text" id="arrear" class="txtBx" /></td>
</tr>
```

Why does the cell containing Days(s) shrink and the width of the table decreases?

Comment: You will get all sorts of quirky behaviour when you have a different amount of cells in each row. To avoid this in your example, make sure you always have a total of 4 cells in each row... either 4 `<td>` in each row or filled in with colspan. Ideally it would look more like [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/92tjbznw/).

Also, formatting your table markup makes it a lot easier to read.

Comment: Plus, make sure you comment CSS with `/* comment */`; don't use `//` to comment CSS.

Comment: @misterManSam Thank you. Instead of applying colspan="2" in the first row, it works fine if two blank cells are added.